# How to save Google Inbox Reminders?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, google-calendar-reminders

Google Inbox will be shut down on 2019-04-02.

Is there any software/service that can automatically convert Inbox Reminders to mail messages to myself or to Google Keep Notes?

Answer (score 1):

Based on **[Inbox to Gmail transition guide](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/9117840?p=transition_to_gmail&visit_id=636724172285751393-924345176&rd=1)**, Reminders can be accessed and set via other Google apps (mostly by Google Calendar) so you shouldn't lose any of your Reminders after Inbox gets discontinued.

Anyway, to back up your Reminders you can always use **[Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/)**:

[image: 0]

And here are few guides on how to deal with Reminders in Gmail:

- **[https://www.reddit.com/r/inbox/](https://www.reddit.com/r/inbox/comments/a5bry4/my_reminders_solution_to_gmail/)**
- **[https://www.fastcompany.com/90237978/](https://www.fastcompany.com/90237978/heres-how-to-recreate-google-inboxs-best-features-in-gmail)**